# Prove - In $\frac{1}{{2}^{\lambda }}\leq \frac{1}{{\lambda }^{d}}$, there exists a large value of $\lambda$, so that the equation holds for any $d$.

Tags: inequality

This problem appears in some material about cryptography related to negligible and non-negligible functions.

In the material says :

epsilon is negligible if

For all $d$, there exists some $\lambda_d$ such that
$$
\lambda \geq \lambda_d:\epsilon \left(\lambda  \right)\leq \frac{1}{{\lambda }^{d}}
$$

Then, how I can prove formally that in the following equation:

$$
\frac{1}{{2}^{\lambda }}\leq \frac{1}{{\lambda }^{d}}
$$

there will exist a large value of $\lambda$, such that for any value of $d$ the equation will hold? So that means that this function is negligible

Note: $\lambda$ and $d$ are positive reals

Thanks

Comment: Use the dollar sign or a pair of them on both sides of the equation.

Comment: Do you mean, "there will exist a value of $d$, such that for any value of $\lambda$ it will hold it?"

Comment: Please also clarify the domain of $d$ and $\lambda$ - I assume that both are positive reals?

Comment: Did you mean, $\lambda \geq \lambda^d : \cdots$?

Comment: yes, that is what I meant

Comment: Now that I've read about Negligible functions on Wikipedia, I think the definitions is: $\epsilon$ is negligible if for any $\epsilon$ *there exists some constant* $\lambda_d$ *such that* $\epsilon(\lambda) \leq 1/\lambda^d$ for all $\lambda \geq \lambda_d$. In that case, your question should be exactly that which is found in @martycohen's answer (he uses $L(d)$ to represent $\lambda_d$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can show is that
for every $d$ there is a $L(d)$ such that
$\frac{1}{{2}^{\lambda }}\leq \frac{1}{{\lambda }^{d}}$
for $\lambda > L(d)$.

$\frac{1}{{2}^{\lambda }}\leq \frac{1}{{\lambda }^{d}}$
is equivalent to
${2}^{\lambda }\geq {\lambda }^{d}$
or $\lambda \ln 2 \geq d \ln \lambda$
or ${\lambda \ln 2 \over \ln \lambda}\geq d $.

Since ${\lambda \over \ln \lambda}$ is unbounded
and increasing for
$\lambda > e$, once we find a solution to
${\lambda  \over \ln \lambda}\geq {d \over \ln 2} $,
we have found the desired $L(d)$.

Note: The solution to ${x \over \ln x} = y$
is about $x = y \ln y$. You can readily find more exact results -
one place I know of is
de Bruijn's "Asymptotic Methods in Analysis".

Comment: thanks @marty cohen, I have been thinking in the first part of the solution that I mentioned, but I was missing the rest of it. It was very helpful your post

Answer (score 0):

This is false. No matter what $\lambda$ is, the value of $1/\lambda^d$ can be made arbitrarily small by choosing ever larger values of $d$. This is because the function $f(d) = 1/\lambda^d$ is decreasing and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = 0$.

Since $1/2^\lambda$ is a constant, there is bound to be some critical value of $d_0$ such that $1/\lambda^d \leq 1/2^\lambda$ for all $d \geq d_0$.

Explicitly, we may solve $1/2^\lambda = 1/\lambda^{d_0}$ to get $d_0 = \log_{\lambda}2^\lambda$.

Comment: I found this in a book about negligible and non-negligible functions so that is why I needed that proof

Comment: You may have copied the question wrongly, for the way you stated it, the assertion is false.

Comment: I have added more information to this problem

Comment: The new information you added doesn't make my argument any less applicable - I guess the function $\epsilon(\lambda) = 1/2^\lambda$ is not negligible then?

Comment: no, according to the material is negligible